Send an email from SQL Server using CLR Assembly (microsoft modern authentication)
I have created a class library project to send an email using Azure.Identity, Microsoft.Graph. after that, I complied into DLL when I tried to create Assembly in SQL Server it threw error

Assembly 'MSGraphMail' references assembly 'system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe, version=4.0.4.1,


how to find the perfect version of my dll refers i.e version=4.0.4.1
how to package all the dlls which is reference in my class library project i.e exactly what they want

CREATE ASSEMBLY PhoenixMail FROM 'C:\MSGraphMail.DLL' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE

 Assembly 'MSGraphMail' references assembly 'system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe, version=4.0.4.1, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: version, culture or public key mismatch). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.
                Assembly 'System.Text.Json' references assembly 'system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe, version=4.0.4.1, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where the referring assembly came from. Still, that operation has failed (reason: version, culture or public key mismatch). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

I also complied system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe but still it throws same error
Thank you

Is there some reason you want to make mail delivery part of the SQL Server's process space? Why aren't you using an external service, container or application to dequeue messages from outside SQL Server?

we followed the same CLR for the last 10 years it refers to multiple projects so I can not change those projects if I fix them here then only those project will work

if you have any ideas about using Microsoft Graph Mail auth in SQL server please let me know it will be very helpful.
